# Returning Items in scrapy's start_requests()

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a scrapy spider that takes as input many urls and classifies them into categories (returned as items). These URLs are fed to the spider via my crawler's `start_requests()` method.

Some URLs can be classified without downloading them, so I would like to `yield` directly an `Item` for them in `start_requests()`, which is forbidden by scrapy. How can I circumvent this?

I have thought about catching these requests in a custom middleware that would turn them into spurious `Response` objects, that I could then convert into `Item` objects in the request callback, but any cleaner solution would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a spider middleware and overwriting the start_requests() would be a good start.

In your middleware, you should loop over all urls in start_urls, and could use conditional statements to deal with different types of urls.

- For your special URLs which do not require a request, you can

  - directly call your pipeline's process_item(), do not forget to import your pipeline and create a scrapy.item from your url for this
  - as you mentioned, pass the url as meta in a Request, and have a separate parse function which would only return the url
- For all remaining URLs, your can launch a "normal" Request as you probably already have defined

Comment: Thanks! I did not know it was possible to access the pipeline from the middleware, it is probably the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which pipeline do I have to call though? And if I have no user defined pipelines, which is the "default pipeline"? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Downloader Middleware to do this job.

In `start_requests()`, you should always make a request, for example:

```py
def start_requests(self):
    for url in all_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url)
```

However, you should write a downloader middleware:

```py
class DirectReturn:
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        image_url = request.url
        if url in direct_return_url_set:
            resp = Response(image_url, request=request)
            request.meta['direct_return_url': True]
            return resp
        else:
            return request
```

Then, in your `parse` method, just check if key `direct_return_url` in `response.meta`. if yes, just generate an item and put response.url to it and then yield this item.