# How to pass scrapy data without any URL Request?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Python 3 and latest scrapy. When I passing some CSV data with another callback function without any URL. It's showing **TypeError: Request URL must be str or unicode, got NoneType:**

My question is How to pass data without any URL?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import csv


class AppsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def start_requests(self):
        with open('data.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            rows = csv.reader(file)

            for row in rows:
                url = row[0]
                title = row[1]
                developer = row[2]
                price = row[3]
                desc = row[4]
                rating = row[5]

                items = {
                    'url': url,
                    'title': title,
                    'developer': developer,
                    'price': price,
                    'desc': desc,
                    'rating': rating

                }
                yield scrapy.Request(None, meta=items, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_it)

    def parse_it(self, response):

        url = response.meta['url']
        title = response.meta['title']
        developer = response.meta['developer']
        price = response.meta['price']
        desc = response.meta['desc']
        rating = response.meta['rating']

        if int(rating) > 4:
            parse_items = {
                'url': url,
                'title': title,
                'developer': developer,
                'price': price,
                'desc': desc,
                'rating': rating
            }

            yield parse_items
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and resolved it with a mix of different solutions. You will need a custom download middleware that prevents the request from going to the downloader and what you had.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import csv
import json




class AppsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    custom_settings = {
    "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {"yourproject.middlewares.AppsSpiderDownloaderMiddleware": 1},
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('data.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            rows = csv.reader(file)

            for row in rows:
                url = row[0]
                title = row[1]
                developer = row[2]
                price = row[3]
                desc = row[4]
                rating = row[5]

                items = {
                    'url': url,
                    'title': title,
                    'developer': developer,
                    'price': price,
                    'desc': desc,
                    'rating': rating

                }
                # need protocol in url else scrapy will error
                yield scrapy.Request(url="http://", meta=items, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_it)

    def parse_it(self, response):

        data = json.loads(response.text)
        url = data['url']
        title = data['title']
        developer = data['developer']
        price = data['price']
        desc = data['desc']
        rating = data['rating']

        if int(rating) > 4:
            parse_items = {
                'url': url,
                'title': title,
                'developer': developer,
                'price': price,
                'desc': desc,
                'rating': rating
            }

            yield parse_items
```

AppsSpiderDownloaderMiddleware.py

```
import json
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

class AppsSpiderDownloaderMiddleware:
    
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        return TextResponse(
            url=request.url,
            status=200,
            body=json.dumps(request.meta).encode('UTF-8'),
            request=request
        )

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        pass

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have passed "None" in this line as the first argument.

```
yield scrapy.Request(None, meta=items, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_it)
```

Pass your 'URL' there!

Comment: Yes, But I would like to pass without any url request

Comment: You can't pass URL in meta. URL is a mandatory parameter for the request method.

Comment: Do you have way to pass data from start_requests to another function

Comment: yield scrapy.Request(url, meta=items, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_it) . This would do it. (change None to url)

Comment: If your end goal is that code that starts in `start_requests` ends up yielding items without first sending a request, then this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35300052/939364